# confusing characterset displaying issue in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, character-encoding

I have an Android-Project on 2 pc's . A & B (2 computers).
Same do have the same content. (Updated to Head)

In one instance I get different characters displayed then in the other:
computer A, which characters are displayed correctly:
[image]

computer B, which has weired placeholders.:
[image]

Any help, what to setup for B, so it shows the corect characters ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to click that **Spinner (ISO-8859-1)** to make it **UTF-8** .You need to copy and agai paste the right content.then it will start showing correct ones again :

[image]

Comment: I need it on ISO-8859-1. As you can see in the screen. The characterset is for both machines the same. I need ISO-8859-1 to get the right values in my Java-Strings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related with the file encodings, that could be different in both computers. 
You can check at File > Default settings > File Encodings.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have the same settings on both machines.